# Tomcat not logging until file is "touched"

Tags: tomcat, logging, windows-explorer

Really weird situation here: our tomcat access logfile is showing 0 bytes and an out-of-date modified date in Windows (Server 2012) Explorer. It's apparently empty and WinScp agrees and is not copying it - presumably because it apparently has not changed or is apparently empty. We kinda "know" that the file is being modified though.

However, as soon as we open the logfile in Notepad++ it "updates" and we see 731KB and data in the file though the timestamp remains old. Even if we just TYPE (i.e. cat) the file we update the size. What on earth could be the cause? Is it just an explorer issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> buffered
>   Flag to determine if logging will be buffered. If set to false, then access logging will be written after each request. Default value: true

So if you want to see immediate changes to that file, add `buffered = "false"` to the attributes of your access log valve.

When `buffered` is set to `true`(default value), the JVM will start to flush the content ONLY IF the buffer has reached its specified capacity, note that flushing doesn't guarantee that the system will subsequently write the data to physical device immediately,  though it's often the case; In addition, the log file practically is never closed, the `valve` just keeps flushing new content to it.

That probably explains why the modified date is intact.

Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

Comment: I am seeing (in procmon) that the java.exe process *IS* writing the file at 9:14. However the date modified in explorer is still 8:59.

Comment: Have you not followed my advice yet?

Comment: I would if it made sense for us: a) it's a peformance issue to disable buffering (this is a prod environment) and b) the file *is* being written periodically. We like buffering, it seems to be working (according to procmon the file is written periodically).

Comment: So what you are worried about exactly?

Comment: We copy the log to a reporting server every few minutes with WinSCP (`get -neweronly`). Until a few days ago it worked fine. Now it copies nothing because it thinks the file it's copying is old. Basically we want our logs.